# Exception in thread, bound must be positive at java.util.random.nextInt and at main

Tags: java

As a new beginner in Java, I am having trouble with a text adventure game, and as I work on it, I realized I was unable to run it.  I have searched Google, looked here, and found no answer to how to fix this problem.

Here's my error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bound must be positive
at java.util.Random.nextInt(Random.java:388)
at iproject.IProject.main(IProject.java:47)
```

and here is my code:

```
package iproject;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author twinbranch*/
public class IProject {

/**
 *
 * @param args
 */
public static void main (String[] args) {

Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
Random rand = new Random();


String[] enemies = {  };
int maxEnemyHealth = 75;
int enemyAttackDamage = 25;


int health = 100; 
int attackDamage = 50;
int numHealthPots = 3;
int healthPotionHealAmount = 30;
int healthPotionDropChance = 33; //Percentage

boolean running = true; {

GAME:
while (running) {
System.out.println();

int enemyHealth = rand.nextInt(maxEnemyHealth);
String enemy = enemies[rand.nextInt(enemies.length)];
System.out.println("\t# " + enemy + "has appeared! #\n");
```

The second error:

```
public int nextInt(int bound) {
if (bound <= 0)
throw new IllegalArgumentException(BadBound);
```

I do not want to post the whole code for this, because it would take up approximately 400 lines.

So, my question is, does anyone know what is wrong with my code?  What errors am I making with this code?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `enemies.length` is zero.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is enemies is empty and you need to define it. That is, `enemies.length = 0`, and hence

```
// will never work unless enemies is initialized and enemies.length > 0.
String enemy = enemies[rand.nextInt(enemies.length)];
```

So consider and make sure enemies are initialized like this :

```
String[] enemies = {"A","B"}; // however way you want it to be
```